# How do I get a website to change from two columns to one column with responsive design?

Tags: html, css, media-queries, css-grid

I am making a simple web design where, on a web page, the logo and description are in the top right corner. The three images of bottles I have are in the bottom left corner.

I want to make the website responsive, but I want the 2 columns to change to one column when switching to a mobile screen. So on a smaller screen, the logo and description would be on-top of each other (like a hero-display) and the three images directly below it, horizontally aligned. How would I go about doing this?

Comment: Please check bootstrap grid layout 
 https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If what I imagine from your question you are looking for could be achieved using [Flex Box](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).

Run this example in full-page and shrink and expand the window to see the mobile breakpoint.

```css
.top-nav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

.bottles {
  display: flex;
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
    .top-nav {
      justify-content: center;
    }
    .bottles {
      justify-content: center;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="top-nav">
  <span>Website Logo</span>
</div>

<div class="bottles">
  <span>Bottles</span>
</div>
```

Comment: This worked thank you! I was trying to use grid and flex box at the same time and that wasn't working out to well, but this worked exactly how I needed it to.

Comment: I like to remember to use Flex Box if what I want to layout within a container is only mainly concerned with one direction, either in a row or column, and to use grid if the container needs to be concerned with both directions at the same time. A lot of times just composing flex box containers is all you need.

I believe a grid could achieve what you want too, maybe I'll update the answer with that later.